# perl CGI.pm: lists vs strings to build pages

Tags: perl, cgi.pm

Is there a reason why CGI.pm examples rely on list concatenation rather than on string concatenation?  are the two interchangeable?  think

```
print q->hidden(-name =>'rm', -value => $var).
      q->submit(-name =>"rm$var");
```

vs.

```
print q->hidden(-name =>'rm', -value => $var),
      q->submit(-name =>"rm$var");
```

I have a specific reason for asking.  it is very convenient to build up a page from strings.  after all, perl understands scalar strings as basic types.

however, I am completely perplexed by some odd behavior in the string concat context.  Specifically, I have encountered occasional cases in which the $var in the hidden is not the same as the one in the submit button.  I could work around this, but I would rather understand CGI.pm .

could someone please explain whether string concat should work?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you change the default value of `$,`,

```
print EXPR1, EXPR2;
```

and

```
print EXPR1 . EXPR2;
```

produce the same result if the expressions aren't context-specific. The functions in question always return an HTML string, so you're good.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that the two examples have the same effect (well, [as ikegami says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28533499/7231), unless you have changed `$,`). The only difference is, of course, that in the first example, `print` is passed one string and in the second example, it gets two.

But have you read the [comments about the HTML generation functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used) in recent versions of the CGI.pm documentation?

> All HTML generation functions within CGI.pm are no longer being
>   maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they
>   relate to fundamentally broken page rendering.
>
> The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm
>   are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You
>   should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns.
>   See CGI::Alternatives for an example of using CGI.pm with the
>   Template::Toolkit module.
>
> These functions, and perldoc for them, will continue to exist in the
>   v4 releases of CGI.pm but may be deprecated (soft) in v5 and beyond.

I would seriously consider moving way from these functions (and, indeed, CGI.pm itself) for new work.

Comment: great advice.  this is a new project, and I primarily wanted to move to what the "standard" is.  learning and moving to deprecated is not my plan.